# How to correctly add 3 columns with 3 particular cells to a table on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging, cross-join

*Note: The following information was created artificially just for educational purposes.*

The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM dapp.credentials WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM dapp.credentials )
```

gets the following row:

```
|  id  | email          | password       | first_name | member_type | validated |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5000|perkins@drit.com|1234perkins     |Mickey      | regular     |1          |
```

Now this other query:

```
SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM dapp.members
WHERE user_id = ( SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM dapp.members )
```

gets this other row:

```
| cellphone     | address             | zipcode | 
-------------------------------------------------
| (787)-142-6952|4108 Wheeler Ridge Dr|99563    |
```

So, how can I create a query that gets a row like this?

```
|  id  | email          | password       | first_name | member_type | validated || cellphone     | address             | zipcode | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  5000|perkins@drit.com|1234perkins     |Mickey      | regular     |1          || (787)-142-6952|4108 Wheeler Ridge Dr|99563    |
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM dapp.credentials WHERE id = ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM dapp.credentials )
JOIN
(SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM dapp.members
WHERE user_id = ( SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM dapp.members ))
```

But I got this error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'JOIN (SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode FROM
> dapp.members WHERE user_id = ( S' at line 2

May I know what did I do wrong with my last query?

Comment: WHERE has to appear after join please review manual page for order in which clauses should appear, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: There is no apparent relationship between these tables so nothing to join on..Is that really your model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `CROSS` join of the 2 queries:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM dapp.credentials 
  WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM dapp.credentials)
) t1 CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT cellphone, address, zipcode 
  FROM dapp.members 
  WHERE user_id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM dapp.members)
) t2;
```

Comment: It works pretty well! Thank you, would you mind to explain to me what's the use of `t1` and `t2`, or why is it valid to use them that way with `CROSS JOIN` ?

Comment: @NoahVerner t1 and t2 are the aliases of the subqueries. You refer to the columns returned by a subquery with the alias of the subquery: t2.cellphone is the column cellphone from the subquery t2. t1.* are all the columns of the subquery t1. The CROSS JOIN creates all combinations of the rows of the subqueries, but since there is only 1 row in each of them the result is 1 row.